# Histogram overlay not visible

Tags: r, histogram, normal-distribution

I need to overlay a normal distribution curve based on a dataset on a histogram of the same dataset.

I get the histogram and the normal curve right individually. But the curve just stays a flat line when combined to the histogram using the add = TRUE attribute in the curve function.

I did try adjusting the xlim and ylim to check if it works but am not getting the intended results, I am confused about how to set the (x and y) limits to suit both the histogram and the curve.

Any suggestions? My dataset is a set of values for 100 individuals daily walk distances ranging from min = 0.4km to max = 10km

```
bd.m <- read_excel('walking.xlsx')
hist(bd.m, ylim = c(0,10))
curve(dnorm(x, mean = mean(bd.m), sd = sd(bd.m)), add = TRUE, col = 'red')
```

Comment: Please provide example data, and code, any error/warnings.

Comment: There aren't any errors. the data set 100 random values ranging from 0.4 to 10.

Comment: Help us to help you, provide random data with set.seed, and your code, so we are on the same page, and can understand your problem.

Comment: for the histogram, I just used the hist() function. the dataset with the values are saved to a variable called bd.m.
code for histogram - hist(bd.m, ylim = c(0,10), main = average  walking distances.)
curve (dnorm(x, mean= mean(bd.m), sd = sd(bd.m), add = TRUE)

Comment: [EDIT](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61266338/edit) your post, please.

Comment: sorry new here is what I have edited enough.

Comment: Can you edit and add your example data `dput(head(bd.m))`, and where is x is coming from?

Comment: Try setting `freq = FALSE` in the call to `hist`

Comment: okay copies the dataset is not working. Its just a data frame with two columns one goes from 1 - 100 other with random values from 0.4 - 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set `freq = FALSE`in the call to `hist`. For example:

```
dt <- rnorm(1000, 2)
hist(dt, freq = F)
curve(dnorm(x, mean = mean(dt), sd = sd(dt)), add = TRUE, col = 'red')
```

[image]